# Cannot view CSS error in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been trying to track down a problem in Internet Explorer. My client sees the products on a certain page as all stretched out. I can view the problem via http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ but not in an actual PC browser with Internet Explorer 8. How can this be tested and then fixed?

This is the page: 
  http://maxwellshousedc.com/wordpress/rugs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the problem using IE8. However, when I turned on compatibility mode it went away. Check that you are not running in compatibility mode for this site.